# c# - static method or not, which one is the best?

Tags: c#, oop, methods, static

I know there is some posts on that but I didn't find the answer I'm looking for, and its simple.

I know calling a method static or not (instanciation (OOP)).

Example, using static:

```
using System;

namespace Projet_Test
{
    class surfacesCalcul
    {
        public static int calc_air(int a, int b){
            int result = a * b;

            return result;
        }
    }

    /*
     * ##########################
     * ##########################
     */

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(surfacesCalcul.calc_air(4,5));
        }
    }
}
```

You call the class(surfacesCalcul).Method and you can access the Method.

--

Normal, using OOP:

```
using System;

namespace Projet_Test
{
    class surfacesCalcul
    {
        public int calc_air(int a, int b){
            int result = a * b;

            return result;
        }
    }

    /*
     * ##########################
     * ##########################
     */

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            surfacesCalcul calculMeThis = new surfacesCalcul();

            Console.WriteLine(calculMeThis.calc_air(4,5));
        }
    }
}
```

You create an instantiation and then you can access the methods in the class.

--

[My Question]
Which one is the best, I'm just wondering why using static method more than from an instance or the inverse. Is there a real reason or both are good. Is there a best time to use one more than the other?

Comment: to put it simply static methods are called form the class name `ClassName.StaticMethod()`. you cannot call them from an instance

Comment: Whenever this sort of question comes up my recommendation is to: *consider* Dependency Injection over static methods. If the [pure] method was *private* then .. that's a different question.

Comment: What makes you so sure it's as simple as "static or non-static"? If it were that simple, surely you would have found the answer?

Comment: @RadioSpace yes I know this. Sorry if my post was not clear, but thats what I said. Im just wondering why using static method more than from an instance or the inverse. Is there a real reason or both are good. Is there a best time to use one more than the other? - I'll update my question

Comment: i prefer to use static when its possible and not static when its not possible. i dont create instanciation. so it depends on the method

Comment: oh i use static as tools and the instance as the working members

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll argue both sides and you can choose.

Consider your first example with a static function:

```
namespace Projet_Test
{
    class surfacesCalcul
    {
        public static int calc_air(int a, int b){
            int result = a * b;

            return result;
        }
    }

    /*
     * ##########################
     * ##########################
     */

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(surfacesCalcul.calc_air(4,5));
        }
    }
}
```

This is fine if you never care about overriding or any kind of inheritance.

Now consider this example:

```
class surfacesCalcul
{
    public virtual int calc_air(int a, int b){
        int result = a * b;

        return result;
    }
}
class surfacesCalcul2 : surfacesCalcul {
   public override int calc_air(int a, int b)
   {
      var g = base.calc_air(a, b);
      return g*2;

   }
}

/*
 * ##########################
 * ##########################
 */

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        var calculMeThis = new surfacesCalcul2();

        Console.WriteLine(calculMeThis.calc_air(4,5));
    }
}
```

You're not changing the "correctness" of the program at all just allowing polymorphism to do its thing.

This example it really to trivial for it to really matter. I would prefer the route with the class since static methods can't have instance variables and you can't do any kind of dependency injection, which makes unit testing so much easier. The object instantiation also allows for different instances to contain different state information where static can't contain any instance specific data.